# Making a histogram of a dictionary

Tags: histograms, charts, linguistics

I am trying to make a histogram of the dictionary where each bin is how many characters in a word, and the height is the frequency of words with that many characters. I'd like to make one for the English dictionary and one for the Spanish dictionary to be able to compare the two. Thank you.

Comment: Does something like `BarChart[KeySort[Counts[StringLength /@ RandomWord["CommonWords", 50]]], ChartLabels -> Automatic]` work for you? (Replace `RandomWord["CommonWords", 50]` with `DictionaryLookup[]` if you want the whole dictionary.)

Comment: not quite but your post helped me figure it out. Histogram[StringLength /@ DictionaryLookup[]]. Thank you

Comment: An extended example for many dictionaries is available under `Applications` on the doc page for [Histogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html).